# native calling screen animation stops when dialog activity display on screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I have on dialog activity with 2 buttons which is being display when native caller id screen displays. Two buttons are click-able and also I can pick up and reject call by android native screen buttons. 
Problem is when this dialog displays, animation of native call screen stops. I have seen this things in [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50cnVlY2FsbGVyIl0.)  app and also [Current Caller Id](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webascender.callerid&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53ZWJhc2NlbmRlci5jYWxsZXJpZCJd) app. I have also used following some codes 
**Manifest.xml**

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:taskAffinity=""
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
android:windowAnimationStyle="@android:style/Animation.Translucent"
android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent"
android:windowIsTranslucent="true"
```

And **activity.java**

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and **adding flags from intent call**

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, activity.class);
i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);         
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

I have tried lots of things to achieve this, How can I create dialog so caller id animation don't stop. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I run into the same problem. Did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: No, It is still stopping animation. If you find anything than post your answer here I will accept it. That might help other peoples.

Comment: Dharmik: I have solution that works well and does not stop animation, check it out: https://github.com/inez/CustomIncomingCallScreen

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a solution that works well for me (and does not stop animation), here it is: https://github.com/inez/CustomIncomingCallScreen